# Extending the Python interactive shell

Tags: python, shell, interactive, readline, interactive-shell

I'd like to extend the Python interactive shell to allow execution of non-python specific statements or commands. The idea being, if you type something on the prompt that would raise a `NameError` what you typed could be parsed for known external commands, and only it failing to find an external command, raise the `NameError`.

I'm not quite sure where to start, I tried calling `code.InteractiveConsole().interact()` inside a `try: / except NameError` but that didn't work

I read the documentation for the `cmd` module, but I looks like its designed JUST for calling external commands and ignores python statements.

The goal is a simple (its for a very small, GUI-less system) command shell that can be scripted with python (rather than sh)

Where should I be looking?  A pure Python solution is ideal.

Comment: IPython does exactly this.  I would start by checking out its [InteractiveShell](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html) and [Magic](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/api/generated/IPython.core.magic.html) classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this documentation: http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/interactive/tutorial.html 
When it becomes using python as a shell replacement, I think are pretty much covered.

Comment: This looks like it will be great- looks like its pure python! Thanks :)